# async SMS sending function is not getting data from textbox WPF c#

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, sms, async-await, task

I am trying to make an async function to send a text message one by one by getting data from grid view in a loop.

What I have managed to do so far is following:

```
 public async void asyncSmsSend()
    {
        try
        {
            btnSend.Content = "Sending...";

            await sendSmsFunc();

            btnSend.Content = "Sent";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private Task sendSmsFunc()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                srprt = new SerialPort(prt, 115200);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                srprt.Open();

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                srprt.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                srprt.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" +tbNmber.Text+ "\"\r\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                srprt.Write(tbMessage.Text + "\x1A");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                //btnSend.Content = "Sent";
                srprt.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //btnSend.Content = "Failed";
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                //btnSend.Content = "Send Again";
            }
        });

    }
```

currently I am simply trying to send async msg by taking data from textboxes on the form and it is giving me

"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"
As I am new in these type of programming and need help.

PS. I after the above problem I will have to use following to get values from DataGridView one by one and send msgs asynchronously. Plz tell me how will I use the loop. 
Thanks

```
            int i = dgvResults.SelectedIndex;
            DataRowView v = (DataRowView)dgvResults.Items[i];

            sIDCardNum = (string)v[0];
            Name = (string)v[1];
            Nmbr = (string)v[3];
            Msg = (string)v[4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a UI control from another thread, the only thread allowed is the UI thread, to solve that problem, you have two solution, either use the Dispatcher BeginInvoke each time you use a UI element like this :

```
    ...
 srprt.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async () =>
 {
    srprt.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + tbNmber.Text + "\"\r\r");
 }));

 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async () =>
 {
    srprt.Write(tbMessage.Text + "\x1A");
 }));
      ...
```

or don't access those controls from that async method and pass the needed parameters to it

```
private Task sendSmsFunc(string phoneNumber,string message)
```

**Update**

regarding your second issue about how to loop through a list of GridView items, the best and elegant solution is as follow :

-define a proper model that will hold the information of each row let's say a class person :

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

-in you window codebehind (or ViewModel), first implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface (which is a way to notify the UI to be updated each time a property is changed ) and create a collection of that Model:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _peopleCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PeopleCollection
    {
        get { return _peopleCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _peopleCollection)) return;
            _peopleCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        PeopleCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){Name = "Person1" ,PhoneNumber = "num1"},
            new Person(){Name = "Person2" ,PhoneNumber = "num2"}
        };

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

 }
}
```

-define your UI in Xaml:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>           
    </ListView>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Loop" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
```

-to loop through the GridView Items all what you need to do is to loop through the ObservableCollection

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var person in PeopleCollection)
        {
            await sendSmsFunc(person.PhoneNumber, person.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ps: don't forget to set the `DataContext`:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Used the 2nd Option. Its Simpler I think. Can u plz help me with 2nd problem now.

Comment: check the update ...I hope that's enough details for you